# Count/sum observations based on the contents of column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that lists litter cleanup events.

```
year              user items
2016 Individual(Patty)     4
2016  Individual(Mary)    70
2017        Green Team   250
2017 Individual(Larry)     1
2018   Individual(Rob)    56
2018            Team 2    14
2018   Individual(Rob)    11
```

I'm trying to create a summary table for this information, grouped by `year`. I'm looking for: total number of cleanup events (each observation is an event), total number of items, total number of users. I also need to break down this info by user type. If the `user` column contains `"Individual"`, then they are considered an individual user. If it does not contain `"Individual"`, then they are considered a group user.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018),
                 user = c("Individual(Patty)", "Individual(Mary)", "Green Team", 
                          "Individual(Larry)", "Individual(Rob)", "Team 2", 
                          "Individual(Rob)"),
                 items = c(4, 70, 250, 1, 56, 14, 11)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(total_users = n_distinct(user),
            total_items = sum(items), 
            total_cleanups = n(), 
            )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    year total_users total_items total_cleanups
#>   <dbl>       <int>       <dbl>          <int>
#> 1  2016           2          74              2
#> 2  2017           2         251              2
#> 3  2018           2          81              3
```

But I don't know how to count/sum observations based on the contents of the `user` column. I'm looking to create something like this:

```
year total_users total_items total_cleanups indiv_users group_users indiv_items group_items indiv_cleanups group_cleanups
2016           2          74              2           2           0          74           0              2              0
2017           2         251              2           1           1           1         250              1              1
2018           2          81              3           1           1          67          14              2              1
```

I'm still pretty new to R. I've tried searching around for a solution for a while now and I'm not coming up with anything. I'm thinking I just don't know how to phrase what I'm wanting to do accurately. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution where you create a new `type` column which distinguishes groups and individuals and summarize based on that. Then you use `pivot_wider` to shape the data to the desired format.

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018),
                 user = c("Individual(Patty)", "Individual(Mary)", "Green Team", 
                          "Individual(Larry)", "Individual(Rob)", "Team 2", 
                          "Individual(Rob)"),
                 items = c(4, 70, 250, 1, 56, 14, 11)
)



df_total <- df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(total_users = n_distinct(user),
            total_items = sum(items), 
            total_cleanups = n())

df_team <- df %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(
    str_detect(user, 'Individual') ~ 'indiv',
    str_detect(user, 'Team')       ~ 'group')) %>%
  group_by(year, type) %>%
  summarize(users = n_distinct(user),
            items = sum(items),
            cleanups = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type,
              names_glue = "{type}_{.value}",
              values_from = users:cleanups,
              values_fill = 0)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.


left_join(df_total, df_team)
#> Joining, by = "year"
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>    year total_users total_items total_cleanups indiv_users group_users
#>   <dbl>       <int>       <dbl>          <int>       <int>       <int>
#> 1  2016           2          74              2           2           0
#> 2  2017           2         251              2           1           1
#> 3  2018           2          81              3           1           1
#> # ... with 4 more variables: indiv_items <dbl>, group_items <dbl>,
#> #   indiv_cleanups <int>, group_cleanups <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>